# Sending a tweet from a C# Application (unattended)

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweetsharp

How can I send a tweet from an unattended C# application?  So far, I've tried TweetSharp, but that isn't working for me (no errors, but no success either). Here's the background info...
I have set up two twitter accounts to test this (lets call them TwitterSender and TwitterReceiver). TwitterReceiver is "following" TwitterSender. I went to dev.twitter.com and logged in as TwitterSender and clicked the "Create New App" button.  From here, I was able to find things called "API Key", "API Secret", "Consumer Key", "Consumer Secret", "Access Token", and "Access Token Secret". When I'm logged in as TwitterSender I can see that I have granted read/write/direct message access. How can I tie all this together so that I can simply run the C# console application and have it send a tweet ("Hello World!") from TwitterSender so that any followers (e.g. TwitterReceiver) will get it? I'm OK with hard-coding user/password in plain-text. In the code below, I get no errors at all, but ultimately TwitterStatus ends up being null, and there is no indication that a tweet was sent either from the perspective of TwitterSender or TwitterReceiver.

```
TwitterClientInfo twitterClientInfo = new TwitterClientInfo();
twitterClientInfo.ConsumerKey = ConsumerKey; //Read ConsumerKey out of the app.config
twitterClientInfo.ConsumerSecret = ConsumerSecret; //Read the ConsumerSecret out the app.config
TwitterService twitterService = new TwitterService(twitterClientInfo);
twitterService.AuthenticateWith(AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret);
Console.WriteLine("Enter a Tweet");
string tweetMessage;
tweetMessage = Console.ReadLine();
TwitterStatus twitterStatus = twitterService.SendTweet(tweetMessage);
```

Comment: I find it hard to understand based on your wall-of-text how your code is misbehaving....

Comment: You likely will not be accomplish this from a console application without initially displaying a browser window for the user to authenticate through. Once you have an access token (and refresh token if Twitter provides the option) you will be able to manage access without a browser. If you have the tokens, TweetSharp will work just fine - is there a particular part of the code that isn't working for you?

Comment: Yes, you should really read up on OAuth 2.0 protocol to understand how this stuff works.

Comment: Thanks Goose - I added the important bits of the code I'm trying...No errors, but unfortunately no tweets either. twitterStatus on the last line of code is null.  Is it correct that I really have to have a human user interact in some way with the code?  I would have thought that's what the "Secret" was all about, no?

Comment: Kind of, the OAuth process uses that information to first request a request token that is in turn used to get an access token.  If you are using Tweetsharp, go to github and take a look at the examples: https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp

Comment: Some platforms offer a method of browserless access, but I'm fairly certain that Twitter is not one of them. The point of OAuth is that the user authenticates with Twitter and Twitter provides your third-party app with an limited time Access Token to retrieve/send data. This way the user allows access to your third-party app without having to share his or her credentials with you.

Comment: Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is send out a tweet when an event occurs (e.g. when a row is created in the database).  So my plan was to have a Windows service or database trigger that would send out a tweet when that happened.  It needs to do this in an unattended manner of course.  Is that just not possible?

Comment: Reiterating the above, basically no that is not possible. At least initially, you will need user interaction to generate an access token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working finally! In short, to send a tweet from, say, a Windows form without requiring a user to log in, you would do the following:

1. go to dev.twitter.com, log in as the account you want to send tweets from, and then create an "Application".  A twitter "Application" in this sense is really just an authorization mechanism and not something that a user interacts with at all.
2. You will be asked for a website during the process of creating the application...After watching a Turkish video tutorial on how this was done, I entered http://www.google.com/tr, but it's likely that Uzbekistan ("uz" I believe) would work equally well).  No, I have no idea why you need this.
3. Leave "Callback URL" blank and uncheck "Allow this application to sign in with Twitter".
4. Set the permissions of your application to read/write
5. Generate your OAuth keys - there should be four keys:  the "API Key" (AKA Consumer Key), "API Secret" (AKA ConsumerSecret), "Token Key", and "Token Secret".
6. Now, go to twitter.com and log into your account (different than dev.twitter.com).  Under "Settings" (hidden under the gear icon I think), there should be an "Apps" tab where you should see the application that you just created.  You may need to grant it permissions from here (or it may already be set). You can also revoke permissions here.
7. Using Visual Studio 2012 and .NET framework 4.5 (NOT VS2010), get TweetSharp from NuGet. This project is no longer maintained or supported by the original developer, so don't expect much documentation or guidance if things don't work.
8. Write your code. For example, in a button click event...

   ```
   var service = new TweetSharp.TwitterService("ConsumerKey","ConsumerSecret","TokenKey","TokenSecretKey"); //Replace keys with values from step #5
   var twitterStatus = service.SendTweet(new SendTweetOptions() { Status ="Hello World" });
   if (twitterStatus != null)
   {
   MessageBox.Show("It worked");
   }
   ```

Note - You can't send the exact same tweet more than once per ___ (some undocumented amount of time). When there is an authentication problem, twitterStatus will return null - if that happens, check your keys, perhaps repermission and regenerate them again.